# contains unrecognized parameter: [token]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am getting the following error while trying to send request with custom parameter "TOKEN" to elastic search 5.6.3.

```
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [token]"
  }
```

Is there any configuration that I might need to look into ?

Comment: Could you add the full request parameters and body ?

Comment: the request is http://localhost/_search?pretty=true&token="...",knowing tha it's working in 0.90.12

Comment: The search URI doesn't seem to accept a `token` parameter, see : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. I would add a custom parameters to a request. How  could i do that?

Comment: It would be pointless, your custom parameters wouldn't be taken into account by the ES HTTP endpoint anyway. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I would like to secure the request by adding encrypted tokens

Comment: You should probably have a look at X-Pack, it manages authentication (including tokens) for ES : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-tokens.html